# Firefox Quantum v67 not rendering XSLT (xsl:call-template & xsl:with-param)

Tags: xslt

XSLT is originally working in Firefox Quantum v66 specifically on xsl:call-template and xsl:with-param, but when the latest update of Firefox Quantum v67 came, the page doesn't render the transformations.

Is there any work around for this?

Comment: Not a programming Q suitable for S.O. Please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: Any XSLT based "page"? Or a specific one? Can you show a minimal but complete example? Any errors in Firefox's error console?

Comment: xsl:call-template together with xsl:with-param does not work in the latest version of Firefox Quantum.

Answer (score 0):

Check this url:
https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/1264318
The solution is at the setting of about:config setting privacy.file_unique_origin

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is advised to provide the solution or at least more information here on SO instead of providing only a link.